# Como calcular as notas bimestrais de 10 alunos

Tags: c, c++

Tenho que fazer um código onde se pede para desenvolver um programa que controle as notas bimestrais de 10 alunos de uma sala de aula. O programa em questão deverá executar as seguintes rotinas:

1. Cadastrar os 10 alunos e suas notas;
2. Classificar os alunos cadastrados;
3. Corrigir alunos e/ou notas que tenham sido cadastradas com erros;
4. Pesquisar alunos por nome;
5. Listar alunos aprovados (media >7);
6. Listar alunos reprovados(media <7).

Eu consegui fazer o cadastro, a pesquisa e a edição, so não estou conseguindo fazer com que mostre os alunos aprovados e reprovados. Agradeço desde já a ajuda.
No momento eu estou testado com 4 nomes, para facilitar o teste.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define cls system("cls");

int main(){
    
    int i,j,x,proc,flag,alt;
    char pesq[90];float media;
    struct caderno
    
    {
    char nome[80];
    float n1,n2,n3,n4;
    };
    
    caderno m[5];
    
    //CADASTRO
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    
    printf ("....Cadastro de alunos e suas notas....\n");
    printf ("Nome do aluno:");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets (m[i].nome, 80, stdin);
    
    printf ("Nota do primeiro bimestre:");
    scanf ("%f",&m[i].n1);
    printf ("Nota do segundo bimestre:");
    scanf ("%f",&m[i].n2);
    printf ("Nota do terceiro bimestre:");
    scanf ("%f",&m[i].n3);
    printf ("Nota do quarto bimestre:");
    scanf ("%f",&m[i].n4);
    
    printf ("\n");
    }
    int op;
    do{
        
        printf ("Digite a opcao desejada:\n\n");
        
        printf ("1 - Listar alunos cadastrados\n");
        printf ("2 - Corrigir Dados\n");
        printf ("3 - Pesquisar por aluno\n");
        printf ("4 - Listar alunos aprovados\n");
        printf ("5 - Listar alunos reprovados\n");
        printf ("6 - Sair");
        scanf ("%d",&op);
        switch (op){
    
    //LISTAR
    case 1:{
    printf ("....Listagem de Alunos....");

    for (i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
    for (j=i+1; j<5; j++)
    {
    if ( strcmp(m[i].nome, m[j].nome ) > 0 )
    {
    m[0] = m[i];
    m[i] = m[j];
    m[j] = m[0];
    }
    }
    }
    for (i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
    printf("Nome: %s\n",m[i].nome);
    }
    break;
    
    
        //CORREÇÃO
        case 2:{
        
        char nom[30];
        float n1,n2,n3,n4;
            
        flag=0;
        //cls aqui
        printf ("\n....Editar Dado....\n");
        for (i=1;i<6;i++)
        printf("Nome: %s\n",m[i].nome);
        printf( "\nQual nome desejar editar: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(nom,29,stdin);
               
        for(i=1;i<6;i++)
        if(strcmp(nom,m[i].nome) == 0 )
        {
        flag = 1;   
                
        printf("Novo Nome:");
        fgets(nom,29,stdin);
        strcpy(m[i].nome,nom);
        {
        printf ("Nota 1:");
        scanf ("%f",&m[i].n1);  
        {
        printf ("Nota 2:");
        scanf ("%f",&m[i].n2);
        {
        printf ("Nota 3:");
        scanf ("%f",&m[i].n3);
        {
        printf ("Nota 4:");
        scanf ("%f",&m[i].n4);
        }
        printf("Edicao realizada com sucesso !\n");
        }
        if( ! flag )
        printf("nNome inesistente!\n");
        break;
    }
    
            //PESQUISA
            case 3:{
            //cls aqui
            printf ("\n|....Pesquisa....|\n");
            printf ("Qual aluno deseja pesquisar: \n");
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets (pesq,90,stdin);
            i=0;
            proc=0;
            while (i<5 && proc==0)
            {
            if (strcmp(m[i].nome,pesq)==0)
            proc = 1;
            else
            i=i+1;
            }
            if (proc==1)
            {
            printf ("Aluno pesquisado: %s\n",m[i].nome);
            printf ("Nota 1: %s\n",m[i].n1);
            printf ("Nota 2: %s\n",m[i].n2);
            printf ("Nota 3: %s\n",m[i].n3);
            printf ("Nota 4: %s\n",m[i].n4);
            
            }
            else
            printf ("\nNome invalido");
                
            break;
    }
    
    //ALUNOS APROVADOS
    case 4:{
    
    
    
}
        break;
    
        //ALUNOS REPROVADOS
        case 5:{
    
    
}
        break;
    
        
    //SAIR
    case 6:{
        printf ("Saindo");
        break;
        default:
        printf ("Opcao invalido");
    }
    }
    
}
}
}


}
}while( op!=6 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reveja a utilização de seu array. O índice de um array varia de 0 até tamanho_do_array-1, assim como você declarou `caderno m[5];` não pode fazer `for (i=1;i<6;i++) printf("Nome: %s\n",m[i].nome);` pois estará referenciando uma área de memória fora da área alocada. Por qual motivo você não declara as notas de cada aluno também como um array?

Comment: Para mostrar os alunos alunos/reprovados, você terá que percorrer todo o vetor, e realizar o cálculo, e se satisfazer o cálculo, imprimir em tela.